# 6 is a prime number? Misunderstanding something in the definition of a prime number

Tags: prime-numbers, definition

Hi I cant seem to find anything about this, I'm sure I am just missing something simple but it is driving me crazy!

From my textbook, the definition of a prime in $\mathbb{Z}$ is:

If $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ is neither $0$ nor a unit (only $1$ and $-1$ in $\mathbb{Z}$) we say that $a$ is **prime** iff, whenever $a$ divides a product, that is $a \mid bc$ where $b,c \in \mathbb{Z}$ it follows that $a\mid b$ or $a\mid c$ or both.

My question is do we first have to assume that $a$ is irreducible? the textbook doesn't imply so. We know later that prime $\implies$ irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}$.

The example I'm having trouble with:

$6\mid 24 = 2\cdot 12$, then $6\mid 12 \implies 6$ is prime?

We also see that $6\mid 12 = 3 \cdot 4$ and $6 \nmid 3$ and $6 \nmid 4 \implies 6$ is not prime.

What am I missing?

Edit: does it have to be true in all cases where $6 \mid bc$?

Thanks

Comment: Hi @liamod! $p$ is prime if "$p| ab$ $\implies$ $p|a$ or $p| b$" $\textit{for all}$ $a$ and $b$. In your case, $6$ is not prime because the condition fails for at least one pair of $a$ and $b$: $a = 3$ and $b = 4$ as you have shown.

Comment: $a | bc  \implies a |b \text{ or } a|c$ has to hold for every possible choice of $b,c$ for $a$ to be prime. You've supplied one counterexample ($b=3$, $c=4$) and so $a$ is not prime.

Comment: $6 \mid 2\cdot 3$, but $6$ doesn't divide $2$ and $3$.

Comment: $$
\begin{align}
\text{right: } & a\nmid b \\ {} \\ \text{wrong: } & a\not|b \\ {} \\ \text{right: } & a\mid b \\ {} \\ \text{wrong: } & a|b
\end{align}
$$
The two labeled "right" above are coded as `a\nmid b` and `a\mid b`; the others are `a\not|b` and `a|b`. (The lack of ability of so many mathematicians to learn simple points like this amazes me. I don't know how they do it.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are missing the word “whenever”. Yes, $6\mid2\times12$ and $6\mid12$. But it doesn't follow from this that $6$ is prime because it doesn't follow from this that **whenever** $6\mid bc$, then $6\mid b$ or $6\mid c$. And, in fact, as you have noticed, $6\mid3\times4$, but $6\nmid3$ and $6\nmid4$.

Comment: Ok perfect thanks! So I just go until I find a counter example and then I know it isn't prime.

Comment: @liamod Yes, that is correct.